# Angular 2 router doesn't match a path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I try the following code in **Plunkr** `PageNotFoundComponent` is loaded in my view:

**src/app-routing.module (excerpt)**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

When I remove the `wildcard` path I get the desired result (component `one` is loaded in the view):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/one', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

What am I missing?

Here's a plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/MxM5JCJmwHVVSuTdfWZg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `@NgModule` like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    OneModule,//<- before root routing module
    AppRoutingModule, 

  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, PageNotFoundComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Since `OneModule` was after `AppRoutingModule`, your paths in `OneModule` are lost in `AppRoutingModule's` wildcard path.

Comment: that was the fastest and best answer I've ever had! Thank you! It works now!

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov haha, glad I could help!